# Nextjs13 pass variable from page file to layout file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to set the layout conditionally on some pages it's "FULL" and on others, it's "BlANK". I need to pass variables from page to layout saying layout type BLANK or FULL.

and In the layout file, I am adding a layout depending on the variable.

But I cannot pass this variable to the layout file in nextjs13 is there a way to solve this problem? I tried "Home.layout = 'Blank';", "getStaticProps", and "getServerSideProps" but nothing helps.

Here is the code for that.
Page.js

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      layout: "Blank"
    },
  };
}

// export async function getStaticProps() {
//   return { props: { layout: 'Blank' } }
// }


let Home = () => {
  return (
    <>      
        <SalesPoint />
    </>
  );
}

Home.layout = 'Blank';

export default Home;
```

and in the layout file

```
const layouts = {
  Blank: BlankLayout,
  Full: FullLayout,
};


export default function RootLayout(props) {
  console.log("pageProps", props); // see pageProps here

  console.log("RootLayout", JSON.stringify(props));

  const Layout = layouts[props.children.layout] || FullLayout;

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${kanit.variable} font-sans`}><Layout>{props.children}</Layout></body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

but not of this way working so can you suggest me the way to solve this problem?